# My vps have enough memory,but vm can not run

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

it happened in my vps.

```
[root@kunphen ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         12067         87      11980          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:         87      11980
Swap:            0          0          0
[root@kunphen ~]# java -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

when I change it to "java -Xms16m -Xmx16m -version",it work.
I try many times.Its largest size is 22m,but my memory also have many free zone.

Answer (score 0):

run it like this:

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx384m" play <your commands>
```

or `play "start 60000" -Xms64m -Xmx128m -server`

Comment: Thank you.But I don't really understand "play".what should I enter into command line.